# Маска для номера российских авто

Tags: kotlin, android-edittext, inputmask

Нужно реализовать маску под российские автомобильные номера. Пробую через кастомный InputFIlter. Проблема в том, что в некоторых случаях вместо последнего введенного символа подставляется весь текст - соответственно текст дублируется. Фото для примера: вместо 7 подставился весь текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```
class CustomInputFiler : InputFilter {

private val listChars = listOf('А', 'В', 'Е', 'К', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Х',
    'A', 'B', 'E', 'K', 'M', 'H', 'O', 'P', 'C', 'T', 'Y', 'X')


override fun filter(
    source: CharSequence,
    start: Int,
    end: Int,
    dest: Spanned?,
    dstart: Int,
    dend: Int
): CharSequence {

    return when {
        // корректное удаление (должно быть первым)
        dend > dstart && end == 0 -> ""
        // проверка первого символа
        dend == 0 -> checkOnLatin(value = source, dest = (dest?.isEmpty()) as Spanned)
        // проверка 3 цифр
        dend == 1 -> checkOnDigits(digit = source, dest = (dest?.isEmpty()) as Spanned)
        dend == 2 -> checkOnDigits(digit = source, dest = (dest?.isEmpty()) as Spanned)
        dend == 3 -> checkOnDigits(digit = source, dest = (dest?.isEmpty()) as Spanned)
        // проверка 2 букв после цифр
        dend == 4 -> checkOnLatin(value = source, dest = (dest?.isEmpty()) as Spanned)
        dend == 5 -> checkOnLatin(value = source, dest = (dest?.isEmpty()) as Spanned)
        // проверка 3 знаков для региона
        dend == 6 -> checkOnDigits(digit = source, dest = (dest?.isEmpty()) as Spanned)
        dend == 7 -> checkOnDigits(digit = source, dest = (dest?.isEmpty()) as Spanned)
        dend == 8 -> checkOnDigits(digit = source, dest = (dest?.isEmpty()) as Spanned)
        else -> ""
    }
}


private fun checkOnLatin(value: CharSequence, dest: Spanned): String {

    return if (listChars.any { charInList ->
            charInList.toString() == value.last().toString()
        })
        "$dest${value.last()}"
    else
        "$dest"
}

private fun checkOnDigits(digit: CharSequence, dest: Spanned) =

    if (digit.last().toString().isDigitsOnly())
        "$dest${digit.last()}"
    else
        "$dest"
}
```